# Deploy a django app into azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've followed the [microsoft guide to deploy a flask app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-python) into an azure app service.How can I do the same with a django application?

Comment: There are tutorials already written for this - just do a quick web search.

Comment: i did'nt find any reliable article to do the same and is the reason why i posted this question.It will be very helpful if you can help me find good tutorial/guide.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app) describes how to run an application using the Django web framework on Azure App service web app, please refer to it.

**Update:**

> configuring the web config for and existing django app is not being convered in this tutorial

You could try to create a Django app on Azure portal, and then you could view app project structure and files in App Service Editor, you will see a sample web.config under project folder that would be a reference/guidance for configuring web.config.

[image]

[image]

On the other hand, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#webconfig) to modify or create a web.config file for your Django app.

Comment: Thanks. But configuring the web config for and existing django app is not being convered in this tutorial ( i guess ).It insists on cloning an existing repo and start a project from it. I'm not a veteran in azure and python so pardon me if i'm not right.

Comment: Hi @Scriptonist, I edited the reply, which should help you modify/configure your web.config. And if it is helpful, please vote for it (or mark it as answer), which would help others quickly and easily find it and solve the similar issue.

Comment: Do you have any question about deploying/running an application using the Django web framework on Azure App service web app? Are you able to run your Django web app on Azure App service web app now?